# Values of Integral with Function

Tags: integration, functions

I have an integral $\int_{0}^{1}e^{2x}f(x)dx$. But $f(x)$ is another function ,not an integral. It is a function that is twice differentiable, and $f''(x)=kf(x)$, $k$ is constant. Then there is local max at $(0,1)$ and local min at $(1, -1)$. So what are possible values of the integral? How to use local max and local min to solve the problem? I have one value is $\frac{e^{2}+1}{k-2}$, is this right? What is other values?

Comment: Integrate by parts twice.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please review the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question to provide your motivation/attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will integrate by parts twice:
$$\begin{align}
\int e^{2x}f(x)dx 
&= \frac{1}{2}e^{2x}f(x) - \frac 12\int e^{2x}f'(x)dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2}e^{2x}f(x) - \frac 12\left(\frac 12 e^{2x}f'(x) - \frac 12\int e^{2x}f''(x)dx\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}e^{2x}f(x) - \frac 14 e^{2x}f'(x) + \frac 14 \int ke^{2x}f(x)dx\end{align}$$
Denoting $I = \int e^{2x}f(x)dx$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{1}{2}e^{2x}f(x) - \frac 14 e^{2x}f'(x) + \frac k4I \\
\frac{4-k}4 I &= \frac{1}{2}e^{2x}f(x) - \frac 14 e^{2x}f'(x) \\ 
I &= \frac{2}{4-k}e^{2x}f(x) - \frac{1}{4-k}e^{2x}f'(x) 
\end{align}$$
Hence,
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 e^{2x}f(x)dx &= \left[\frac{2}{4-k}e^{2x}f(x) - \frac{1}{4-k}e^{2x}f'(x)\right]_0^1 \\&= \frac{2}{4-k}e^2f(1) - \frac{1}{4-k}e^{1}f'(1) - \frac{2}{4-k}f(0) + \frac{1}{4-k}f'(0) \\&= -\frac{2e^2+2}{4-k}
\end{align}$$
Since $x=0$ and $x=1$ are critical points, we have $f'(0)=f'(1)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$f''(x)-kf(x)=0;\;f(0)=1,f'(0)=0,f(1)=-1$

Dolving the DE we get
$$f(x)=a e^{\sqrt{k} x}+b e^{-\sqrt{k} x};\;f'(x)=a \sqrt{k} e^{\sqrt{k} x}-b \sqrt{k} e^{-\sqrt{k} x}$$
Setting the initial conditions
$$\begin{cases}
a+b=1\\
a-b=0\\
a e^{\sqrt{k}}+b e^{-\sqrt{k}}=-1
\end{cases}
$$
$$a=\frac12;\;b=\frac12$$
$$\frac12 e^{\sqrt{k}}+\frac12 e^{-\sqrt{k}}=-1$$
$$\frac{e^{\sqrt{k}}+e^{-\sqrt{k}}}{2}=-1\to k=-\pi^2$$
and finally
$$f(x)=\frac{ e^{\pi i x}+b e^{-\pi i x}}{2}\to f(x)=\cos (\pi  x)$$
and then
$$\int_0^1 e^{2 x} \cos (\pi  x) \, dx=\left[\frac{e^{2 x} (\pi  \sin (\pi  x)+2 \cos (\pi  x))}{4+\pi ^2}\right]_0^1=$$

$$=-\frac{2 \left(1+e^2\right)}{4+\pi ^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Ok so we know a few things to start with $f''(x)=kf(x),f(0)=1,f(1)=-1,f'(0)=f'(1)=0$. We can go ahead and solve this in a few ways:

---

### ODE:

$$f''(x)-kf(x)=0$$
let $f(x)=Ae^{\lambda x}\therefore f''(x)=A\lambda^2e^{\lambda x}$ so:
$$Ae^{\lambda x}\left[\lambda^2-k\right]=0$$
This means that $\lambda=\pm\sqrt{k}$ so:
$$f(x)=Ae^{\sqrt{k}x}+Be^{-\sqrt{k}x}$$
now we can use our initial and boundary conditions:
$$f(0)=A+B=1$$
$$f(1)=Ae^{\sqrt{k}}+Be^{-\sqrt{k}}=-1$$
$$f'(0)=A\sqrt{k}-B\sqrt{k}=\sqrt{k}(A-B)=0$$
$$f'(1)=A\sqrt{k}e^{\sqrt{k}}-B\sqrt{k}e^{-\sqrt{k}}=\sqrt{k}e^{-\sqrt{k}}\left(Ae^{2\sqrt{k}}-B\right)=0$$
now using:
$$\begin{cases}A+B=1\\A-B=0\end{cases}$$
You can solve for $A$ and $B$ then you should be able to work out $k$ from there.

---